# datepicker PHP multiple sets of times

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

When using datepicker function from PHP, how can it be configured to do more than one set of From/To dates?  This works perfect for the first From/To dates but does not engage for subsequent sets of dates:

```
$pagetext .= '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">'.NL;
$pagetext .= '<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>'.NL;
$pagetext .= '<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>'.NL;

$pagetext .= '<script>'.NL;
$pagetext .= '$(function() {'.NL;
$pagetext .= '$( "#from" ).datepicker({'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'defaultDate: "+1w",'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'changeMonth: true,'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'numberOfMonths: 1,'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'onClose: function( selectedDate ) {'.NL;
$pagetext .= '$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );'.NL;
$pagetext .= '}'.NL;
$pagetext .= '});'.NL;
$pagetext .= '$( "#to" ).datepicker({'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'defaultDate: "+1w",'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'changeMonth: true,'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'numberOfMonths: 1,'.NL;
$pagetext .= 'onClose: function( selectedDate ) {'.NL;
$pagetext .= '$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );'.NL;
$pagetext .= '}'.NL;
$pagetext .= '});'.NL;
$pagetext .= '});'.NL;
$pagetext .= '</script>'.NL;
```

Statements in a loop:

Comment: you can lose that stitch in a very quick single bind.

Comment: You may want to look at [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Because that is kind of a mess to read.

Comment: You are using `#from` instead of `.from`
Basically change `#from` to `.from` and then on the elements change `id="from"` to `class="from"`. and same for `#to`

Comment: I don't id="from" to change to class="from" and when I changed the #from and #to to .from and .to, it stopped working.

Comment: The input statements that use this function looks like this and it works the first time in the loop but not the second time through:
<input type="text" size="12" id="from" name="rentfrom['.$row['from'].']"  value="'.$txtdate.'" />  
The from and to work with a calendar box the first time through but on box comes up on the second From/To statements in the loop.
The rentto is the same with different variables.

Comment: I did not realize the id="from" was on the input statement.  I had to keep the id="from" but added the class="from" and now it does work on the second iteration.  THANK YOU for your help honerlawd!!